# fill the gap between dates in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with collected data by year-month but sometimes there is a month where no data is collected. This way

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("car,year,month,amount
Mazda,2012,02,2344
Ford,2012,04,235234
Mazda,2012,03,3455
Mazda,2012,04,43554
Mazda,2012,05,9854
Mazda,2012,06,32556
Ford, 2013,01,2345"), sep = ",", header = TRUE)

> df
    car year month amount
1 Mazda 2012     2   2344
2  Ford 2012     4 235234
3 Mazda 2012     3   3455
4 Mazda 2012     4  43554
5 Mazda 2012     5   9854
6 Mazda 2012     6  32556
7  Ford 2013     1   2345
```

I want fill the gaps this way (given two dates, "from" = 2012/01/01 , "to" = 2013/12/01):

```
    car year month amount
 Mazda 2012     1      0
 Ford  2012     1      0
 Ford  2012     2      0
 Mazda 2012     2   2344
 Ford  2012     3      0
 Ford  2012     4 235234
 Mazda 2012     3   3455
 Mazda 2012     4  43554
 Mazda 2012     5   9854
 Mazda 2012     6  32556
 Mazda 2012     7      0
 Mazda 2012     8      0
 Mazda 2012     9      0
 Mazda 2012    10      0
 Mazda 2012    11      0
 Mazda 2012    12      0
 Ford  2013     1   2345
 Ford  2013     2      0
 Ford  2013     3      0
 Ford  2013     4      0
 Ford  2013     5      0
 Ford  2013     6      0
 Ford  2013     7      0
 Ford  2013     8      0
 Ford  2013     9      0
 Ford  2013    10      0
 Ford  2013    11      0
 Ford  2013    12      0
 Mazda  2013    1      0
 Mazda  2013    2      0
 Mazda  2013    3      0
 Mazda  2013    4      0
 Mazda  2013    5      0
 Mazda  2013    6      0
 Mazda  2013    7      0
 Mazda  2013    8      0
 Mazda  2013    9      0
 Mazda  2013   10      0
 Mazda  2013   11      0
 Mazda  2013   12      0
```

My first idea was to generate a "dates dataframe as a sequence this way

```
min.date <- as.Date("2012/01/01")
max.date <- as.Date("2013/12/01")

gen.dates <-
  seq(from = mid.date,
      to = max.date,
      by = "month") %>% as.data.frame()
```

and then JOIN but I discovered that is not as simple as it seems, so I assume there is a cleaner way maybe using dplyr

Comment: `tidyr::complete(df, car = unique(car), year = unique(year), month=1:12, fill=list(amount=0))`

Comment: great! but I can't set the ending date this way to 2014, for instance...

Comment: totally can. i'll expand my answer

Comment: `data.table::setDT(df)[,.SD[.(month=1:12),, on = "month"], by = .(year, car)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

```
read.table(textConnection("car,year,month,amount
Mazda,2012,02,2344
Ford,2012,04,235234
Mazda,2012,03,3455
Mazda,2012,04,43554
Mazda,2012,05,9854
Mazda,2012,06,32556
Ford,2013,01,2345"),
           sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) -> xdf
```

Heavyweight `tidyverse` way:

```
dplyr::glimpse(
  tidyr::complete(xdf, car = unique(car), year = unique(year), month=1:12, fill=list(amount=0))
)
## Observations: 48
## Variables: 4
## $ car    <chr> "Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "For...
## $ year   <int> 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013...
## $ month  <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8...
## $ amount <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 235234, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2345, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2344, 3455, 43554...
```

All base R:

```
merge(
  expand.grid(car = unique(xdf$car), year = unique(xdf$year), month=1:12),
  xdf, by = c("car", "year", "month"), all.x = TRUE
) -> xdf

xdf$amount <- ifelse(is.na(xdf$amount), 0, xdf$amount)

dplyr::glimpse(xdf)
## Observations: 48
## Variables: 4
## $ car    <fct> Mazda, Mazda, Mazda, Mazda, Mazda, Mazda, Mazda, Mazda, Mazda, Mazda, Mazda, Mazda, Mazda, Mazda, Ma...
## $ year   <int> 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013...
## $ month  <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8...
## $ amount <dbl> 0, 2344, 3455, 43554, 9854, 32556, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23...
```

Head-to-head:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  tidy = tidyr::complete(xdf, car = unique(car), year = unique(year), month=1:12, fill=list(amount=0)),
  dplyr = xdf %>%
    group_by(car, year) %>%
    complete(month = 1:12, fill = list(amount = 0)),
  base = {
    merge(
      expand.grid(car = unique(xdf$car), year = unique(xdf$year), month=1:12),
      xdf, by = c("car", "year", "month"), all.x = TRUE
    ) -> x2
    x2$amount <- ifelse(is.na(x2$amount), 0, x2$amount)
  }
)
## Unit: microseconds
##   expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq       max neval
##   tidy 2553.802 3036.262 4233.912 3613.672  5046.737 12219.712   100
##  dplyr 5639.261 6851.680 9396.590 7686.171 10273.043 70357.399   100
##   base  848.400 1055.845 1593.015 1194.247  1656.759  9594.898   100
```

You can also do the expansion (e.g. years as you asked):

```
tidyr::complete(xdf, car = unique(car), year = 2012:2014, month=1:12, fill=list(amount=0))
```

or

```
merge(
  expand.grid(car = unique(xdf$car), year =2012:2014, month=1:12),
  xdf, by = c("car", "year", "month"), all.x = TRUE
) -> x2
x2$amount <- ifelse(is.na(x2$amount), 0, x2$amount)
```

And, then layer in other metadata:

```
read.table(textConnection("car,year,month,amount
Mazda,2012,02,2344
Ford,2012,04,235234
Mazda,2012,03,3455
Mazda,2012,04,43554
Mazda,2012,05,9854
Mazda,2012,06,32556
Ford,2013,01,2345"),
           sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) -> xdf


merge(
  expand.grid(car = unique(xdf$car), year =2012:2014, month=1:12),
  xdf, by = c("car", "year", "month"), all.x = TRUE
) -> x2
x2$amount <- ifelse(is.na(x2$amount), 0, x2$amount)

data.frame(
  car = c("Mazda", "Ford"),
  country = c("JP", "US"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) -> car2country_df

merge(x2, car2country_df)
```

*or* via `tidyverse`:

```
tidyr::complete(
  xdf, car = unique(car), year = 2012:2014, month=1:12, fill=list(amount=0)
) %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(car2country_df)
```

Comment: could be possible to add another column just to be preserved?. COUNTRY(JP for MAzda and USA for Ford) I ve tried but no success so far

Answer (score 0):

Check out `tidyr` package and `complete`. Use `fill = list(amount = 0))` to fill in missing values as indicated by @markus below.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(car,year) %>% complete(month = 1:12, fill = list(amount = 0))
# A tibble: 48 x 4
# Groups:   car, year [4]
#   car                                     year month amount
#   <fct>                                  <int> <int>  <dbl>
# 1 "                                Ford"  2012     1      0
# 2 "                                Ford"  2012     2      0
# 3 "                                Ford"  2012     3      0
# 4 "                                Ford"  2012     4 235234
# 5 "                                Ford"  2012     5      0
# 6 "                                Ford"  2012     6      0
# 7 "                                Ford"  2012     7      0
# 8 "                                Ford"  2012     8      0
# 9 "                                Ford"  2012     9      0
#10 "                                Ford"  2012    10      0
# ... with 38 more rows
```

Comment: Add `fill = list(amount = 0))` to `complete`.

Comment: I get 36 rows but 48 are expected. Your code does not fill the gaps for Mazda vehicles. I was not clear enough, my bad. Sometimes ending year is 2018. So how can I set the starting/ending date using your aproach?